# New to api testing pre-request scripts - Automatically getting access token with OAuth 2.0 Grant Type 'Client Credentials'

Tags: api, scripting, request, automated-tests, postman

I have been stuck for days on this and looked through many articles, but can not find a script that can help me.

The basis of the script is to automatically get authorization token, before i use a `POST` method.

As said before when getting a access token for this particular api the grant type is `Client Crentials` and the following fields are needed when manually getting the token :-

`Token Name`, `Grant Type`, `Access Token URL`, `Client ID`, `Client Secrect`, `Scope` and `Client Authentication`.

Is there a simple script that i can do this for me before actually doing the `POST` as it tiresome manually getting the token.

Thanks in advance with any help.

Kind Regards

Just an update i have found a way of actually getting the token now , so if you do the following.

1. Add a new request
2. Select 'Post'
3. Enter the api url
4. Click 'Body'
5. Click 'x-www-form-urlencoded'
6. I entered the following 'Keys'(enter your own corresponding 'values')   - 'client_id', 'client_secret', 'scope' and 'grant type'
7. Click 'Send'

This will get you your token, i now need to find a way to either extract the token in a new request or find a way of putting this in the pre-request scripts, so I am able to enter the data need as 'raw' JSON.

Again if anyone can help, would appreciate it.

Kind Regards

Comment: I did not want to start a new topic, but is there anyway of getting a token when using a 'Get' mothod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this be any help to you? Or at least get you closer to what you need?

If you add this script to the `Collection` level `pre-request script` it will get the token and set this as the `jwt` variable. You can use this variable in the `Headers` for the main requests, using the `{{jwt}}` syntax - This script also gets the `expiry_in` value from the token response and sets this as a variable.

On each request in the collection, it will run the script and check to see if you have the `AccessTokenExpiry` and `jwt` properties in the environment file, it also checks to see if the token has expired. If any of those statements are true, it will get another token for you. If those are ok, it will use what you have set.

```
const moment = require('moment')

const getJWT = {
    url: `<your token base path>/Auth/connect/token`,
    method: 'POST',
    header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'urlencoded',
        urlencoded: [
            {key: 'grant_type', value: 'client_credentials'},
            {key: 'scope', value: '<scope details>'}
            {key: 'client_id', value: 'your creds'}
            {key: 'client_secret', value: 'your creds'}
        ]
    }
}

var getToken = true

if (!_.has(pm.environment.toObject(), 'AccessTokenExpiry') 
    || !_.has(pm.environment.toObject(), 'jwt')
    || pm.environment.get('AccessTokenExpiry') <= moment().valueOf()) {
} else {
    getToken = false
}

if (getToken) {
    pm.sendRequest(getJWT, (err, res) => {
        if (err === null) {
            pm.environment.set('jwt', `Bearer ${res.json().access_token}`)

            var expiryDate = moment().add(res.json().expires_in, 's').valueOf()
            pm.environment.set('AccessTokenExpiry', expiryDate)
        }
    })
}
```

To access the Collection level elements, if you hover over the collection name and click the `...` icon, this will display a list of menu options. Select `edit`.

[image: Access collection level elements]

Comment: Hey Danny, thank you for you input i actually found a different way, in the body i used the x-www-form-urlencoded and then added the keys that I needed, and it actually returns, the access token, when it expires, and token type. I now have the problem of extracting the token and chain for the next request.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the other method that you found - Maybe you could add an update on to the original question

Comment: Hey Danny, I have now updated with information I have found

Comment: so you have another request that's separate to get the token? The solution that I offered would do all that for you (if you change some of the details) - When you place that script in the Collection level pre-request script, it will get the token and set it to a variable for you - This is all done before it sends the 'main' request.

Comment: I think i amended what I originally posted, changing someone the details to match your criteria. Let me know if this is better.

Comment: He Danny, is it possible to have this pre-request Script, in the actual request rather than the collection, as in my collection I will be hitting other api's, that have different authorization, Im dealing with chaining requests that call both the internal and the external api's

Comment: You can put it anywhere you like :) It's just trial and error really - I don't know your context so I can only provide something that might work but it's not going to solve all the use cases that you may have.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll see if this method works :)

Comment: I did not want to start a new topic, but is there anyway of getting a token when using a 'Get' mothod?